Visual Studio Code Clangd only use clang-tidy for project. Problems with external include
I want to use clang-tidy in VsCode to establish a consistent coding style.
The project does not use Cmake and I am currently not feeding compiler-options to clang-tidy. I am running into problems including a header file which is not present in the working directory and which also does not belong to standard headers.
In a .c-file, it is included like #include <folder_name/header_name.h>. The include shows the error clang(pp_file_not_found).
So I want clang-tidy to include the folder folder_name.
In some threads I already read that clang-tidy should be fed with the include-paths from c_cpp_properties.json. Here, I am already including folder like "C:/Program Files (x86)/path_to_folder/folder/**". With clangd deactivated and C IntelliSense activated, I can see that the include works. But how can get clang-tidy to find the folder?
My setup is:

C/C++ IntelliSense in VsCode is deactivated
Clang-tidy is currently invoked by clang-tidy --config-file .\.clang-tidy file.c
The config-file looks like the following:

Checks:          cppcoreguidelines-*
WarningsAsErrors: true
FormatStyle:     google

What I already tried:

Include path in c_cpp_properties.json
Invoke clang-tidy like clang-tidy --config-file .\.clang-tidy -- -IFOLDER_PATH file.c


c_cpp_properties.json is a configuration file specific to Microsoft's C/C++ VSCode plugin. It's not used by clangd or clang-tidy.
Clangd and clang-tidy use compile_commands.json for configuration. Please see https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#compile_commandsjson for some discussion of this file and how to generate it.
